# Copy & paste nth row to other sheet (mod)

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code (working).

```
Sub Copy_Ten()
 Dim X As Long, LastRow As Long
 Dim CopyRange As Range
 LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 For X = 1 To LastRow Step 4
     If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
         Set CopyRange = Rows(X).EntireRow
     Else
         Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, Rows(X).EntireRow)
     End If
 Next
 If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
 CopyRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
 End If
 End Sub
```

On sheet 2 it always starts at A1. I would like it to look for the next space and continue on.

The code I have would be `Range("A1").End(xldown).Select` however I do not know where to put it.

So ultimately sheet 2 would never, after the first time start from A1.... as there would be a growing list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use that code but wrap it in a with function like so

```
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    lastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
End With
```

Then change

```
CopyRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
```

To

```
CopyRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lastRow2)
```

To make this a bit clearer try the following

```
Sub Copy_Ten()
    Dim X As Long, LastRow As Long, PasteRow As Long
    Dim CopyRange As Range
    LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    With Sheets("Sheet2")
        PasteRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    For X = 1 To LastRow Step 4
        If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
            Set CopyRange = Rows(X).EntireRow
        Else
            Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, Rows(X).EntireRow)
        End If
    Next
    If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
        CopyRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & PasteRow)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: SO it should look like this. I have tired but no go `Sub Copy_Ten()
 Dim X As Long, LastRow As Long
 Dim CopyRange As Range
 With Sheets("Sheet2")
    lastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 End With
 For X = 1 To LastRow Step 4
     If CopyRange Is Nothing Then
         Set CopyRange = Rows(X).EntireRow
     Else
         Set CopyRange = Union(CopyRange, Rows(X).EntireRow)
     End If
 Next
 If Not CopyRange Is Nothing Then
 CopyRange.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & lastRow2)
 
 End If
 End Sub
`

Comment: stoke a genuies, a genuies

Comment: I should have made it a bit clearer that it was to use a separate variable. Enjoy!